# JQuery compare option with span value and if true put option to disabled

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have select & option like this :

```
<select id="vari" name="variation" data-variation="US Shoe Size (Men's)">
<option id="var8">8</option> 
<option id="var8.5">8.5</option> 
<option id="var9">9</option> 
<option id="var9.5">9.5</option> 
<option id="var10">10</option> 
<option id="var10.5">10.5</option> 
<option id="var11">11</option> 
<option id="var11.5">11.5</option> 
<option id="var12">12</option> 
<option id="var13">13</option> 
<option id="var14">14</option> 
</select>
```

and for example (hidden span) like this :

```
<span class="get">8</span>
<span class="get">8.5</span>
```

wanted to find all option and compare with span values.
if some option has the same value like span with class get (for example) this value can be changed (i've created the span)
it will disable the option.
but the problem it disable all.

```
$('#vari').find('option').each(function() {
    var x = $(this).val();
    var y = $('.get').text();
    if(x = y){
         this.disabled=true;
    }
});
```

what gone wrong here?

Solution :::

```
$('#vari').find('option').each(function() {
    x = $(this).val();
    disable = true;
    $('.get').each(function() {
        if(x === $(this).text()){
            disable = false;
        }
    });
    if(disable){
         $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: I think it is not a good idea to scan for all `.get` elements in every `option` iteration. My posted solution is 2x - 3x faster ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need a double `==` at the moment x and y will always equal the same as you are setting `x = y` in the if statement (please note as `.get` is a class your jQuery `$('.get').text()` could turn a array of text so bare that in mind if there are more then one span with class `.get`.)

```
$('#vari').find('option').each(function() {
    var x = $(this).val();
    var y = $('.get').text();
    if(x == y){
         this.disabled=true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple small issues here. First, you're going to need a nested loop to work that way, second, your comparison in the if is actually assigning y to x, instead of comparing them. In Javascript you have to use multiple equals '==' or even more specific '===' to compare two things.

```
var x,
    disable;
$('#vari').find('option').each(function() {
    x = $(this).val();
    disable = false;
    $('.get').each(function() {
        if(x === $(this).text()){
            disable = true;
        }
    });
    if(disable){
         $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

I haven't tested this, but I think it should work for you. in your loop, one of the issues you were having is your $('.get').text(). $('.get') returns an array of elements, and you were referencing it like it only gets one.

Comment: $('#vari').find('option').each(function() {
    x = $(this).val();
    disable = true;
    $('.get').each(function() {
        if(x === $(this).text()){
            disable = false;
        }
    });
    if(disable){
         $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

**Your code has many issues:**

```
$('#vari').find('option').each(function() { // .each is a loop function
    var x = $(this).val();
    var y = $('.get').text(); // so why is this done in every iteration?
    if(x = y){ // = must be ==
         this.disabled=true; // this is not the right way. Use jquery.prop()
    }
});
```

Furthemore you have multiple elements with `.get` class.
So `var y = $('.get').text();` will just add all values to a string. Output of `y` in your example: `88.5`.

So fill these values in a seperate array first.

How comparison works was mentioned by others already.

The right way how to manipulate the `disabled` property is given in jQuery Docs: 
http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2

And please use `console.log(myVarName);` to debug your code. Many of its outputs are already well discussed on SO. So you will find solutions faster :)

**How it works:**

```
var y = [];
$('.get').each(function() {
  y.push($(this).text());
});

$('#vari').find('option').each(function() {
  var x = $(this).val();
  if (y.includes(x)) {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```